# Reshaping and encoding multi-column categorical variables to one hot encoding

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data which looks as follows:

```
    Owner   Label1  Label2  Label3      
    Bob     Dog     N/A     N/A 
    John    Cat     Mouse   N/A 
    Lee     Dog     Cat     N/A
    Jane    Hamster Rat     Ferret
```

And I want it reshaped to one-hot encoding. Something like this:

```
    Owner   Dog     Cat     Mouse    Hamster    Rat    Ferret   
    Bob     1       0       0        0          0      0
    John    0       1       1        0          0      0    
    Lee     1       1       0        0          0      0
    Jane    0       0       0        1          1      1
```

I've looked around the documentation and stackoverflow, but haven't been able to determine the relevant functions to achieve this. [get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) comes pretty close, but it creates a prefix for each category only when that category appears in a respective column.

Answer (score 4):

Using

```
df.set_index('Owner').stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)
Out[535]: 
       Cat  Dog  Ferret  Hamster  Mouse  Rat
Owner                                       
Bob      0    1       0        0      0    0
John     1    0       0        0      1    0
Lee      1    1       0        0      0    0
Jane     0    0       1        1      0    1
```

Or

```
s=df.melt('Owner')
pd.crosstab(s.Owner,s.value)
Out[540]: 
value  Cat  Dog  Ferret  Hamster  Mouse  Rat
Owner                                       
Bob      0    1       0        0      0    0
Jane     0    0       1        1      0    1
John     1    0       0        0      1    0
Lee      1    1       0        0      0    0
```

Comment: `df.set_index('Owner').stack().groupby(level=0).apply('|'.join).str.get_dummies()`

Comment: Both these methods are reducing the number of rows I have in my dataset? Going from 3159 to 2599. Any clue why?

Comment: @user3297011 duplicated Owner have

Answer (score 3):

You could use `get_dummies` on the stacked dataset, then groupby and sum:

```
pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('Owner').stack()).groupby('Owner').sum()

       Cat  Dog  Ferret  Hamster  Mouse  Rat
Owner                                       
Bob      0    1       0        0      0    0
John     1    0       0        0      1    0
Lee      1    1       0        0      0    0
Jane     0    0       1        1      0    1
```

Comment: This method is reducing the number of rows I have in my dataset? Going from 3159 to 2599. Any clue why?

Comment: Sounds like you've got duplicate owners, probably

Answer (score 2):

#### `sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

o, l = zip(*[[o, [*filter(pd.notna, l)]] for o, *l in zip(*map(df.get, df))])

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

d = mlb.fit_transform(l)
pd.DataFrame(d, o, mlb.classes_)

      Cat  Dog  Ferret  Hamster  Mouse  Rat
Bob     0    1       0        0      0    0
John    1    0       0        0      1    0
Lee     1    1       0        0      0    0
Jane    0    0       1        1      0    1
```

---

#### Same-ish answer

```
o = df.Owner
l = [[x for x in l if pd.notna(x)] for l in df.filter(like='Label').values]

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

d = mlb.fit_transform(l)
pd.DataFrame(d, o, mlb.classes_)

       Cat  Dog  Ferret  Hamster  Mouse  Rat
Owner                                       
Bob      0    1       0        0      0    0
John     1    0       0        0      1    0
Lee      1    1       0        0      0    0
Jane     0    0       1        1      0    1
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) function converts categorical variable into dummy/indicator variables in a single step